# How to post this in Http Body in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, database, http-post

This content want to post with http body.

```
{
"employee": {
    "email": "karan_2016@yopmail.com",
    "password": "qweqwe!23",
    "password_confirmation": "qweqwe!23",
    "cpf": "753.965.641-72",
    "name": "karan",
    "phone": "5824581247"
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add more details in your question about what you tried already.

Comment: Thnx Bisma i solved !

Answer (score 0):

Make `NSMutableRequest` and attach it to the request.
Read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsmutableurlrequest).